# xindy cannot open the temp file

Tags: glossaries, xindy

I have encountered a problem by using xindy within glossaries. After the first call of `pdflatex`, I gave `makeglossaries mytex` in command line. Unfortunately, I got the error

> "LOAD: A file with name C:\Users\xyzxyz~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vEslm0pNhL does not exist".

With some work I found out that the file `C:\Users\xyzxyz~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vEslm0pNhL` has been correctly generated by xindy.pl. However, it cannot be loaded by xindy_lisp.exe, which expected full path name instead of shorted one (DOS style), i.e. `C:\Users\xyzxyzabcabc\AppData\Local\Temp\vEslm0pNhL`. Does anyone have the same issue? How can I get over it?

I use the texlive2011 distribution on Win 7.
My tex file is (the example from glossaries):

```
% This file is public domain
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[style=long4colheaderborder,xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{w}{name={$w$},
sort=w,
description={width},
symbol=m}
\newglossaryentry{M}{name={$M$},
sort=M,
description={mass},
symbol=kg}

\begin{document}

\printglossaries
The width, \gls{w}, is measured in meters. The mass, \gls{M} is measured in kilograms.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a workaround to set another temporary folder for your `makeglossaries` session. First, let's see my execution:

[image: Image 1]

If I type `echo %TEMP%` in the command prompt, the full path for the temporary folder is displayed:

```
C:\>echo %TEMP%
C:\Users\Paulo\AppData\Local\Temp
```

In order to use another temporary folder, it's just a matter of redefining the environment variable `TEMP`:

```
C:\>set TEMP=C:\paulo\mytemp
```

Then you can safely run `makeglossaries` for that command prompt session:

[image: Image 2]

Hope it helps. `:)`

Comment: I have the same problems here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76388/why-xindy-unable-to-execute-here

Comment: We must copy the tex file to xindy's Temp folders, then xindy can work.I don know how to redefine the TEMP folders of makeglossaries in MAC.

Comment: I use xindy --inactive .... to find the temp folder of the xindy, then I copy the test.tex in it--/private/var/folders/9u/3d3d34trdetrgdDEffg/ Then I xelatex test.tex, makeglossaries test, xelatex test.tex there, It works. But it is so dirty, I don't know how to resolve it finely.